# Source for shuls flying in yemos hamoshiach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, synagogue, eretz-yisrael, vehicles-transportation, ymoth-hamoshiach

My son mentioned to me that he learned in school that when Moshiach comes all the shuls (and schools?) will miraculously fly to Eretz Yisroel. What is the source of this idea?

Comment: Your son's Rebbe is the source ;)

Answer (score 8):

The source is [Megila 29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9660&st=&pgnum=57).

> תניא ר"א הקפר אומר עתידין בתי כנסיות ובתי מדרשות שבבבל שיקבעו בא"י
>   שנאמר כי כתבור בהרים וככרמל בים יבוא, והלא דברים ק"ו ומה תבור וכרמל
>   שלא באו אלא לפי שעה ללמוד תורה נקבעים בארץ ישראל, בתי כנסיות ובתי
>   מדרשות שקורין ומרביצין בהן תורה עאכו"כ

Comment: Is there a source that clarifies whether this means the actual buildings will uproot and fly to Israel or whether the congregations will reestablish themselves in Israel?

Comment: @Fred: http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/from-exile-to-redemption-2/04.htm#t79 -- _"In future time," our Sages teach,[80] "all the synagogues and Houses of Study will be transplanted to Eretz Yisrael."
It could be argued that they will be transferred together with the soil on which they stand. This would avert the halachic prohibition against uprooting a synagogue or House of Study unless such an option was stipulated when it was first established.

Sefer HaSichos 5749 [1989], Vol. I, p. 98_ -- you can see there for a discussion on this, but the Lubavitcher Rebbe understood it literally.

Comment: @Menachem Nice source. It is still not explicit if he understood it as saying that they would miraculously fly, or if they would be moved by natural means (the latter of which might fit better with the part about "avert[ing] the halachic prohibition against uprooting").

Comment: @Menachem And by the way, the other meaning I suggested about congregations reestablishing themselves there would also be a literal (if synecdochical) interpretation.